# If Time and Space are intrinsically linked and space is ever expanding then surely time is slowing down

Tags: time, big-bang, cosmological-inflation, space

When we try to imagine the initial expansion after the big bang we see with the CMB that the universe went from initially smaller than a hydrogen atom to what we see today. However, when we try to measure the rate of that expansion it currently defies our current observations of the laws of physics, what if at those initial conditions time as we measure it was infinitely faster than it is currently and gradually slowed down to the point where now we cannot observe a rate change. To repeat my question above if time and space are linked then surely the changes in space will have some similar effect on time?

Comment: It seems to me that the concept of time is somewhat arbitrary: if time was suddenly 'sped up' by a factor of 2 for the entire universe, we wouldn't notice, because *everything* is happening two times faster (including our own perception). Per the theory of relativity, it's only *relative* differences that really matter.